# mySQL get n level affiliates

Tags: mysql

I have a table "affiliates" with columns "user" and "referredBy".

Given a user I wish to get all "n-level" players referred by that user. For n=1 we're just interested in how many players you directly referred:

```
SELECT * FROM affiliates WHERE referredBy = "me"
```

But if someone you refer then refers someone else that person is considered your secondary (n=2) affiliate. For example, if the table looks like:

```
user  | referredBy |
bob   | andy       |
cindy | andy       |
dave  | cindy      |
```

Then Andy's first level affiliates are Bob and Cindy. Dave is his secondary affiliate because Dave was referred by an affiliate of Andy (Cindy).

How can I get all entries representing n-level affiliates for a particular user?

Comment: You are basically asking for a recursive JOIN, which is not possible with MySQL. You can however JOIN the table let's say 3 times, each time aliasing the field as level-1, level-2, level-3 and then only use the level you  would like. However, this is a fixed amount of levels and not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I have written it for 3 levels. Please check whether it works for three levels. Please use correct and good aliases (though I havn't used good one :p)
and please let me know about the results.

I shall check how it can be done for n levels.

```
select
(case when bspp.user is not null and  bsp.user is not null then bs.user else null end) as subsub,
(case when bspp.user is null and bsp.user is not null then  bs.user else bsp.user end) as sub,
(case when bspp.user is null and  bsp.user is null then bs.user else
    case when bspp.user is null and  bsp.user is not null then bsp.user else
            bspp.user
    end 
end
) as user1
 from affiliates bs
left outer join affiliates bsp on bs.referredBy = bsp.user
left outer join  affiliates bspp on bsp.referredBy = bspp.user
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.user AS lev1, t2.user as lev2, t3.user as lev3, t4.user as lev4
FROM affiliates AS t1
LEFT JOIN affiliates AS t2 ON t2.referredBy = t1.user
LEFT JOIN affiliates AS t3 ON t3.referredBy = t2.user
LEFT JOIN affiliates AS t4 ON t4.referredBy = t3.user
WHERE t1.user = "dave";
```

Comment: Sorry for my neglect of this question. Since asking I've lazily resorted to dumping the table and manipulating the data in script. Your second query looks very promising but seems to return an empty set? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75ec0/1

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do so.

First way is to use backend language to generate tree from data. [Here](http://phpflow.com/php/how-to-create-dynamic-tree-view-menu/)  you can find some code examples

Second way requires you to change table structure and use [Nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). 
You can find some examples [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

You can also try just copy-pasting joins, like others suggested, but thats impractical and can take a lot of time and memory on large sets of data.

Comment: There are basically 4 ways - and the Multi-level join is not so impractical given that n is unlikely to exceed 5, say